# make_heap() compilation issue

Tags: c++, linux, stl

compiling following:

```
class Compare
{
   bool cmp(const int& a, const int& b){return a>b;}
};

int main()
{
   vector<int, Compare> v;
   make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare());
}
```

result in compilation error - no class template named 'rebind' in 'class Compare'.
What may be the reason? I use RedHat Linux with gcc.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing parentheses near *begin()* and *end()* and are defining comparator the wrong way. This is what it should probably look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Compare: std::binary_function<int const&, int const&, bool>
{
   public:
   bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b){return a>b;}
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v;
   std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, I do not (this is not copy-pasted code). Still, this is not the reason

Comment: @Tuna, welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions can be edited -- I fixed it for you this time, but please do so yourself in the future if a typo is found.

Answer (score 3):

std::vector<> doesn't have a comparator template argument; it has an *allocator* for its second argument.

You're using your comparator as an allocator in the vector template argument list.

```
class Compare
{
   public:
   bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b){return a>b;}
};

int main()
{
   vector<int> v;
   make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare());
}
```

Comment: So, I need to define an allocator?

Comment: @Tuna no. you need to *remove* the comparator in the vector<> declaration. just use `vector<int>` .

Comment: OK. That is in case I want to use int as a template (as I wrote here). In real code I would like to use another class. And I get the same error.

Comment: @Tuna no worries. So long as your class provides proper copy-semantics there is no reason std::vector<YourClassName> should not work properly. Look again at the code above, however (in this answer) and pay special attention to the way the operator() is overloaded in the Compare class.